# Class and Dropdown list for Javascript file in VS 2013

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2013

I'm working on a AngularJS project using VS 2013 and one of my JS files contains a million functions. It's a pain to navigation through entire code to reach a specific function or piece of code, since there is no functions dropdown list that I can select like it does in CS files.

Is there any way to enable functions and classes dropdown list in VS 2013 or any VS version for that matter? Because I just checked on VS 2010 and it doesn't provide the dropdown list either. Any suggestions?

Comment: My suggestion is to separate the functions in multiple js-files. Also are you sure you need all the million functions in all the pages you include this massive js-file? Even if you have many js-files, your bundling should put them all together for end use.

Comment: so there's no way to view functions in a list?

Comment: In typescript there is the same class/methods-list as in code views but not in js-files. Maybe there is an extension for Visual Studio for this, I don't know.